# Custom CRDs not getting deleted in aks cluster, how to delete that?

Tags: kubernetes, aks, consul

I have installed consul helm repository to default namespace.
Now, want to change it to a custom namespace.

So, deleted the help chart using helm uninstall command.
Now, when I try to install again, getting error as CRDs are already configured earlier, need to cleanup them.

So, ran the below command to check the CRDs.

```
kubectl get CustomResourceDefinition --all-namespaces
NAME                                     CREATED AT
healthstates.azmon.container.insights    2021-09-24T14:19:01Z
ingressgateways.consul.hashicorp.com     2021-09-26T13:17:13Z
servicedefaults.consul.hashicorp.com     2021-09-26T13:17:13Z
serviceintentions.consul.hashicorp.com   2021-09-26T13:17:13Z
servicerouters.consul.hashicorp.com      2021-09-26T13:17:13Z
```

The above CRDs, I need to cleanup all with consul as subtext.

So, I tried deleting one by one.But it got stuck there without deleting them when I ran any command below.

```
kubectl delete crd serviceintentions.consul.hashicorp.com
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io "serviceintentions.consul.hashicorp.com" deleted
```

I waited for 1 hour, but no response so entered ctrl+c to cancel and ran get command again, seems they are not deleted.

Please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: How exactly did you install `consul` using `helm`? Which exact command did you use? When I installed `consul` from `hashicorp` via helm chart, there's no `crd`s at all.

Answer (score 1):

Reference [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/602466/custom-crds-not-getting-deleted-in-aks-cluster-how.html?childToView=602583#comment-602583)

> Can you please perform a kubectl get crd -A -o yaml | grep -i finalizers to check if the delete operation is in deadlock with finalizers set on the CRDs?
>
> In that case, you can perform the following:
>
> ```
>  kubectl patch crd <custome-resource-definition-name> -n <namespace> -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":[]}}' --type=merge
>  kubectl delete crd <custome-resource-definition-name> -n <namespace>
> ```

Above is the response I got in the MSDN forum. But that didn't work for me.
So, I manually edited the CRD by using below command and deleted the finalizer section fromt he CRDs, then it got deleted directly.

```
kubectl edit crd <CRD-Name>
```

Thank you very much for your reply.